# Indexing for entire firebase Realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a firebase Realtime database to store basic user info. One of which being their dislikes.

When trying to get the dislikes data, I require it to filter out the false values and only get the values that equal true. However when running it I get the error `java.lang.Exception: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": ".value", for path "/users/dG9JqcX2WjgfZhJ3HOFGQyYNrs92/Dislikes", to the rules`.  I understand I have to add indexing to the path for this users dislikes to the rules for it to work however what about if another user with a different authentication key tries to access theirs? Won't this have a different path so the error will occur for that user until I add indexing for that section? Is there any way to add indexing to the entire database or automate adding the new path to the rules?

I get the dislikes data by using:

```
myRef.child(userid).child("Dislikes").orderByValue().equalTo(true).get().addOnSuccessListener {
```

And my database structure looks like this:

[image: Database]

Any and all help/tips are appreciated!

Comment: Can you please share the complete error message that you get?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes of course

Comment: What is the expected result when you're using that query?

Comment: @AlexMamo, the true values from that path. In this instance... 'cleankng', 'football' and 'gaming' as they are marked tmas true in the database

Comment: So you basically want the query to return only those **two** keys, "Cleaning" and "Football", right?

Comment: @AlexMamo, yes. However if there is another user who has different values that equal true... These are the keys I would need to get

Comment: So you want to query across all users, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo, Yes if possible

Comment: Do you know the value which you are searching for ahead of time?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, my programs goal is to search for matches in the database of people that have the same dislikes as you.

Comment: It will be a multiple whereEqualTo query or a single one?

Comment: @AlexMamo, Multiple if possible!

Comment: There is no way you can perform multiple whereEqualTo calls in the same query. Please check the duplicate to see a workaround.